¿Cómo crear un calendario de futbol en python?
Estoy realizando un proyecto en python que se llama Torneos de bola, para este proyecto tuve que crear un menú donde el usuario puede configurar los datos del torneo (nombre, equipos participantes, equipos clasificados, puntos por partido ganado y puntos por empate), esta información va a ser almacenada en un archivo llamado "configuración.dat".
Seguidamente cree una serie de menús en los que se pueden agregar, consultar, modificar y eliminar los equipos participantes, esta información se alamcena en "equipos.dat" con la siguiente estructura

Código de equipo ("USA" por ejemplo)
Nombre del equipo ("Estados Unidos")
La posición en la tabla mundial (2)

Sin embargo, para poder trabajar con los equipos se debe crear un diccionario de equipos (equipos_dic) en el cual el código de equipo es la llave que va a permitir acceder a una tupla con la siguiente estructura ("nombre del equipo", La posición en la tabla mundial).
Mi problema consiste en que debo crear un menú que cree un calendario de partidos, en el cual se presenten todos los posibles enfrentamientos (todos contra todos), pero deben estar divididos por fechas, es decir, un país solo debe aparecer una vez por fecha. Yo ya tengo todos los posibles partidos, sin embargo, no logro dividirlos en fechas sin que se repitan los equipos (hay equipos que juegan dos veces en la misma fecha). El calendario es una lista que almacena tuplas (fechas) y así mismo estas almacenan otras tuplas (partidos), las cuales están conformadas por "codigo del equipo 1"(casa) y el "codigo del equipo 2"(visita).
En resumen, necesito corregir estos errores:

los equipos solo pueden aparecer una vez por fecha
no deben existir partidos repetidos ( ("USA","CRC") solo puede aparecer una vez)

Adjunto el código del programa por si alguien me puede ayudar con a solucionar este problema. En este caso estoy trabajando con 6 equipos, pero el programa debe funcionar para cualquier cantidad par de equipos.
Además, adjunto la imagen del resultado (lo que imprime mi código) y otra imagen con la estructura y requerimientos deseados:


    while True: 
        os.system("cls")
        print ("--------------TORNEOS DE BOLA----------------")
        print (" ")
        print ("--------------CREAR CALENDARIO---------------")
        print (" ")
        try:
            equipos=open("equipos.dat","r")
            equipos_dic={}
            ciclo=0
            cantidad=len(equipos.readlines())/3
            equipos.seek(0)
            while ciclo<cantidad:#pasa por todas las lineas del archivo de 3 en tres para recopilar todos los datos (codigo, nombre, posicion)
                codigo=equipos.readline()
                codigo=codigo.replace("\n","")
                nombre=equipos.readline()
                nombre=nombre.replace("\n","")
                posicion=equipos.readline()
                posicion=posicion.replace("\n","")
                equipos_dic[codigo]=(nombre,posicion)#agrega los datos obtenidos al diccionario y vuelve a iniciar con el siguiente equipo
                ciclo+=1
            configuaracion=open("configuracion.dat","r")#abre el archivo de configuracion para comparar la cantidad equipos participantes con la cantidad de equipos registrados
            nombre_configurado= configuaracion.readline()[:-1]
            cantidad_configurada=eval(configuaracion.readline()[:-1])
            while True:#validar que el diccionario de equipos esté completo
                if len(equipos_dic)!=cantidad_configurada:
                    print("ERROR: la lista de equipos no se ha completado")
                    input("Ingrese los equipos faltantes antes de usar este menu, dar <INTRO>")
                    return
                else:
                    break
            lista_equipos=[]
            lista_juegos=[]
            for codigos in equipos_dic:
                lista_equipos.append(codigos)
            parejas=list(itertools.combinations(lista_equipos,2))
            random.shuffle(parejas)
            fechas=[]
            cantidad_fechas=cantidad_configurada-1
            while len(fechas)<cantidad_fechas:#crear lista de fechas
                fecha=[]
                fechas.append(fecha)
            for equipos in lista_equipos:
                contador_fechas=0
                for partidos in parejas:
                    if equipos in partidos:
                        fechas[contador_fechas].append(partidos)
                        contador_fechas+=1
            print(fechas)
            input()
            return
        except IOError:
            input("Primero debe agregar la lista de equipos para acceder a este menu")
            return```



Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Esto no es un problema de codigo.. es un problema de logica.. tendrias que usar un sistema como el real, con una especie de bolillero, donde no se puede repetir el equipo que sacas.. y a medida que pasan las fechas, tampoco se repiten los partidos... llegado un punto, te van a quedar solo 1 o 2 partidos y vas a tener que elegirlos directamente...

Tambien podes hacer al reves, dibujar todos los partidos e ir distribuyendolos en las fechas segun corresponda... pero de vuelta, no es un problema de codigo, es de logica...
